# regex to match groups/chunks of numbers

Tags: php, regex

**Working Solution (Answer below)**

```
$phones = [
    "5141234567, 5144384062",
    "608-909-5003 Home : 629-716-8085",
    "Cell: 705-111-7699 workcell: 547-924-5097",
    "729-242-1353; 718-251-0292",
    "Call 555-1212 or 1-800-555-1212, 1 (949) 637 2826; +1 233 455 7878",
    "6097999388 ext 128",
];


foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    $phone = trim($phone);
    $possibles = [];

    preg_match_all("/(?:[+][0-9]+[ ]?)?[(]?\b0*[0-9]{3}[)]?(?:[ .-]?[0-9]){7}\b/", $phone, $matches);

    echo $phone . ': ' . print_r($matches, true);
}
```

Looking for regex to fetch all occurrences of numbers with spaces hyphens and parenthesis. These are phone numbers in notes entered by users. Need not look for groups of 3 and 4 digit numbers.

Here are some examples that should match. Match any occurrence till the next word or `;` or `,`

1. +1 456 934 7814
2. 09845612345
3. (614)-443 8762

Example log from our current database. Each of these are processed at once as a single line.

1. 614443 7286
2. Cell: 9845122842 Office: 8649984345 (Just the number parts no Cell: or Office: is required to match)
3. 7824562892; 5144459682
4. 5144384412 ext. 282 (Extension or groups with less than 7 digits excluding hyphens, spaces and `()` can be ignored)
5. Call me on +1 8142104482 after 6pm (`+1 8142104482` should match)

**Summary** So, the regex should help pick chunks of numbers (7 or more digits) with optional + at the beginning and `-`, `space`, `()` in between.

**Update**

Got pretty with this one:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+[\-\s]\d+)+/x",
            "Call 555-1212 or 1-800-555-1212, 1 (949) 637 2826; +1 233 455 7878", $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 555-1212
            [1] => 1-800
            [2] => 555-1212
            [3] => 637 2826
            [4] => 1 233
            [5] => 455 7878
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 555-1212
            [1] => 1-800
            [2] => 555-1212
            [3] => 637 2826
            [4] => 1 233
            [5] => 455 7878
        )

)
```

**Expected/Required**

```
[0] => 555-1212
[1] => 1-800-555-1212
[2] => 1 (949) 637 2826
[3] => +1 233 455 7878
```

Comment: Do you know all numbers are at least 10 long or can there be shorter numbers too? Also how do you want 4 parsed, with the _ext._?

Comment: Maybe you could work something out from [this](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=telephone).

Comment: @Halcyon Adding that.

Comment: Do the `Cell:` or `Office:` or the extension also need to be part of the match?

Comment: @LukStorms No. Just the number parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the phone numbers in the examples:

```
[+]?0*(?<=^|[+0\s])(?:(?:[0-9]{1,2}[ ]?)?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?(?:[ .-]?[0-9]){7})\b
```

It'll allow a space, dot or dash before the last 7 characters.
So it would allow `(123) 123-4567` and also `(123) 1-23 45 67`

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/6ipQQ2/5)

Comment: Tried the second one and get this error `PHP Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '?'`

Comment: @mishka Did you use the pattern with double quotes or like this : `preg_match_all ('/(?:[+][0-9]+[ ]?)?[(]?\b0*[0-9]{3}[)]?(?:[ .-]?[0-9]){7}\b/', $text, $pat_array);`

Comment: I tried now with double quotes `preg_match_all("/(?:[+][0-9]+[ ]?)?[(]?\b0*[0-9]{3}[)]?(?:[ .-]?[0-9]){7}\b/",
                "Call 555-1212 or 1-800-555-1212, 1 (949) 637 2826; +1 233 455 7878", $matches);` and it works like a charm. Awesome. 2 negative marks already :(

Comment: Little bit more explanation on each part of the expression would help people like me _/\_

Comment: +284812945282 failed though :(

Comment: @mishka  After some looking, turns out it was because of the wordboundary \b in the middle. Because of the 2 extra numbers that connect, the regex wouldn't match that kind of number. A \b is needed though or it could match only some digits in a long number. So I've updated the regex and the test.  It's longer now.

Comment: @mishka That it became so long was kinda bugging me. So I've changed it again. Now it's using a positive lookbehind instead of a \b

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm.